# Slow performance on first render of restart menu pygame snake

Tags: python, pygame

I have made a simple snake game with the help from the clear code tutorial, and I wanted to added simple feature for the game over screen. My current implementation allows you to press r to replay and q to quit, the method I implemented seems to be working fine, however, on the first restart the performance is very slow and it takes several seconds for the game over screen to be displayed. After the first restart the issue seems to disappear and I don't really understand why it is like this. I figured it has something to do with how I create the objects, but I don't really have a clear understanding of why this is, I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2 as v2
import time
import sys
import random


class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.body = [v2(6, 10), v2(5, 10)]
        self.movement = v2(1, 0)
        self.grow = False

        #grahpics from clear code tutorial

        self.head_up = pg.image.load('graphics/head_up.png').convert_alpha()
        self.head_down = pg.image.load('graphics/head_down.png').convert_alpha()
        self.head_right = pg.image.load('graphics/head_right.png').convert_alpha()
        self.head_left = pg.image.load('graphics/head_left.png').convert_alpha()

        self.tail_up = pg.image.load('graphics/tail_up.png').convert_alpha()
        self.tail_down = pg.image.load('graphics/tail_down.png').convert_alpha()
        self.tail_right = pg.image.load('graphics/tail_right.png').convert_alpha()
        self.tail_left = pg.image.load('graphics/tail_left.png').convert_alpha()

        self.body_vertical = pg.image.load(
                'graphics/body_vertical.png').convert_alpha()
        self.body_horizontal = pg.image.load(
                'graphics/body_horizontal.png').convert_alpha()

        self.body_tr = pg.image.load('graphics/body_tr.png').convert_alpha()
        self.body_tl = pg.image.load('graphics/body_tl.png').convert_alpha()
        self.body_br = pg.image.load('graphics/body_br.png').convert_alpha()
        self.body_bl = pg.image.load('graphics/body_bl.png').convert_alpha()



    def draw_snake(self, board):
        self.update_head_graphics()
        self.update_tail_grahpics()

        for index, block in enumerate(self.body):
            snake_rect = pg.Rect(block.x * cell_size, block.y * cell_size, 
                    cell_size, cell_size)
            pg.draw.rect(board, (0, 0, 0), snake_rect)
            if index == 0:
                board.blit(self.head, snake_rect)
            elif index == len(self.body) - 1:
                board.blit(self.tail, snake_rect)
            else:
                previous_block = self.body[index + 1] - block
                next_block = self.body[index - 1] - block

                if previous_block.x == next_block.x:
                    board.blit(self.body_vertical, snake_rect)
                elif previous_block.y == next_block.y:
                    board.blit(self.body_horizontal, snake_rect)
                else:
                    if previous_block.x == -1 and next_block.y == -1:
                        board.blit(self.body_tl, snake_rect)
                    if previous_block.y == -1 and next_block.x == -1:
                        board.blit(self.body_tl, snake_rect)

                    elif previous_block.x == -1 and next_block.y == 1:
                        board.blit(self.body_bl, snake_rect)
                    elif previous_block.y == 1 and next_block.x == -1:
                        board.blit(self.body_bl, snake_rect)
                    
                    elif previous_block.x == 1 and next_block.y == -1:
                        board.blit(self.body_tr, snake_rect)
                    elif previous_block.y == -1 and next_block.x == 1:
                        board.blit(self.body_tr, snake_rect)

                    elif previous_block.x == 1 and next_block.y == 1:
                        board.blit(self.body_br, snake_rect)
                    elif previous_block.y == 1 and next_block.x == 1:
                        board.blit(self.body_br, snake_rect)


    def move_snake(self):
        if self.grow == True:
            copy_body = self.body[:]
            copy_body.insert(0, copy_body[0] + self.movement)
            self.body = copy_body
            self.grow = False
        else:
            copy_body = self.body[:-1]
            copy_body.insert(0, copy_body[0] + self.movement)
            self.body = copy_body


    def update_head_graphics(self):
        head_relation = self.body[1] - self.body[0]
        if head_relation == v2(1, 0):
            self.head = self.head_left
        elif head_relation == v2(-1, 0):
            self.head = self.head_right
        elif head_relation == v2(0, -1):
            self.head = self.head_down
        elif head_relation == v2(0, 1):
            self.head = self.head_up

    def update_tail_grahpics(self):
        tail_relation = self.body[-2] - self.body[-1]
        if tail_relation == v2(1, 0):
            self.tail = self.tail_left
        elif tail_relation == v2(-1, 0):
            self.tail = self.tail_right
        elif tail_relation == v2(0, -1):
            self.tail = self.tail_down
        elif tail_relation == v2(0, 1):
            self.tail = self.tail_up

    def grow_snake(self):
        self.grow = True

    def reset(self):
        self.body = [v2(6, 10), v2(5, 10)]
        self.movement = v2(0, 0)
        game = Main()
        game.run()
        


class Food:
    def __init__(self):
        self.new_position()
        self.apple_graphic = pg.image.load(
                'graphics/apple.png').convert_alpha()

    def place_food(self, board):
        food_rect = pg.Rect(self.vector.x * cell_size, 
                self.vector.y * cell_size, cell_size, cell_size)
        board.blit(self.apple_graphic, food_rect)

    def new_position(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0, cell_number - 1) 
        self.y = random.randint(0, cell_number - 1) 
        self.vector = v2(self.x, self.y)


class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.board = pg.display.set_mode((cell_size * cell_number, 
            cell_size * cell_number))
        pg.display.set_caption('Snake by Tenos200')
        self.score = 0
        self.snake = Snake()
        self.food = Food()
        self.game_over_menu = False 
        self.game_run = True
        self.SCREEN_UPDATE = pg.USEREVENT
        pg.time.set_timer(self.SCREEN_UPDATE, 120)

    def update(self):
        self.snake.move_snake()
        self.check_boundary()
    
    def draw_elements(self):
        self.snake.draw_snake(self.board)
        self.food.place_food(self.board)

    def check_position(self):
        if self.food.vector == self.snake.body[0]:
            self.food.new_position()
            self.snake.grow_snake()
            self.update_score()

        for block in self.snake.body[1:]:
            if block == self.food.vector:
                self.food.place_food()

    def check_boundary(self):
        if (self.snake.body[0].x >= cell_number or self.snake.body[0].x < 0):
            self.game_over()
        if (self.snake.body[0].y >= cell_number or self.snake.body[0].y < 0):
            self.game_over()

        for block in self.snake.body[1:]:
            if block == self.snake.body[0]: 
                self.game_over()

    def game_over(self):
        self.game_over_menu = True
        game_over_msg = (f'Game over! Score: {self.score}')
        self.display_message(game_over_msg)

    def update_score(self):
        self.score = len(self.snake.body)

    def display_message(self, message):
        self.board.fill(game_over_color)
        font = pg.font.SysFont('timesnewroman', 32)
        text = font.render(message, True, 
                (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))
        textRect = text.get_rect()
        textRect.center = (cell_number*cell_size / 2, cell_number*cell_size / 2)
        self.board.blit(text, textRect)
        pg.display.flip()
    
    def run(self):

        while self.game_run:
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    self.game_run = False
                if event.type == self.SCREEN_UPDATE:
                    self.update()
                if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                    if self.game_over_menu:
                        if event.key == pg.K_q:
                            pg.quit()
                            sys.exit()
                        if event.key == pg.K_r:
                            self.game_over_menu = False
                            self.snake.reset()
                    if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                        if self.snake.movement.x != -1:
                            self.snake.movement = v2(1, 0)
                    if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                        if self.snake.movement.x != 1:
                            self.snake.movement = v2(-1, 0)
                    if event.key == pg.K_UP:
                        if self.snake.movement.y != 1:
                            self.snake.movement = v2(0, -1)
                    if event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                        if self.snake.movement.y != -1:
                            self.snake.movement = v2(0, 1)
            
            if not self.game_over_menu:
                self.board.fill(bg_color)
                self.draw_elements()
                self.check_position()
            pg.display.update()
            clock.tick(framerate)


clock = pg.time.Clock()
framerate = 60
game_over_color = (0, 0, 0)
bg_color = (175, 215, 75)
cell_size = 40 
cell_number = 20

game = Main()
game.run()
```

Comment: when pressing r You should also probably delete Main class to not keep it running, something like `del self` after or before calling `self.snake.reset()` maybe does something since You create another instance of Main but the current one still keeps running

Comment: That does seem to speed up the other instances, but for some reason the first is still slow when loading into the screen. Could it have something to do with the logic of my game loop, or the drawing of the surface?

Comment: question: it happens only once? so say you were playing and the game ended and You pressed "r". now it took a while, it was slow, to load again, right, but say the game ended again and you again pressed "r", would it be slow now to load?

Comment: the probable issue is that when calling `Main()` again you also instantiate `Snake` class (`snake = Snake()`) which means that all those images get loaded too which is probably what slows it down (the same about Food class), so basically what You could do actually is instantiate them outside the Main class

Comment: @Matiiss What I mean is that the first time the game_over method is executed, its really slow compared to loading time after the first restart. If that makes sense. It does happen consistently every first restart.

Comment: are the other restarts fine?

Comment: @Matiiss yes, they are fine.

Comment: @Matiiss after some further investigation, it seems like the drawing of the text, and text_rect in the display_message method is processed slow the first time, I'm still not sure why.

Comment: I am confused as to how that would happen only once, I can only think of it happening every time r is pressed, also when exactly is it slow?

Comment: did You try using my answer?

Comment: It is exactly slow right after the snake collides with the wall and the game_method executed. It is suppose to show a black background and a text, but it just freezes on the collided snake screen. The pressing of the 'r' is not really an issue, it is just the first loading time of the game over background.

Comment: @Matiiss I also tried your answer, that is to instantiate the snake and food outside the __init__ but it did not seem to change anything in terms of loading time.

Comment: maybe remove this line: `pg.display.flip()` in the `display_message()` method of Main class since the screen will get updated anyways by the `pg.display.update()` in the `run()` method so maybe that is the issue. Also don't know if related to the issue but here: `game_over_msg = (f'Game over! Score: {self.score}')` there is no need for those parentheses could be just `game_over_msg = f'Game over! Score: {self.score}'`

Comment: also just so You know that this: `if (self.snake.body[0].x >= cell_number or self.snake.body[0].x < 0):` can be this: `if self.snake.body[0].x >= cell_number or self.snake.body[0].x < 0:` those parentheses are also not necessary (not related for sure but...). about this tho, there are cases when parentheses are necessary for example if You have sth like comparing one thing and two other of which either can be true, then You could do sth like `if condition1 and (condition2 or condition3):`

Comment: @Matiiss massive thanks for all the advice, I have tried to remove the pg.display.flip() but it doesn't seem to fix the issue. Performance on the first load is still slow... I does seem to be the rectangle is causing the issue, because just updating board.fill(bg_color) seems to be working just fine.

Comment: I added another method to my answer, try it and see if that helps

Comment: That seems to do it! The starting up of the game is a bit slower now but I assume that's the way it is when you render these classes. Huge thanks @Matiiss.

Comment: actually now thinking it could have been that it takes a while for it to initialize the system font or sth which makes sense since it probably would be set to global so the next time it already is initialized, but great, I mean usually the games at start load a while so that is expected

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
snake = Snake()
food = Food()

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.snake = snake
        self.food = food
```

this way those classes will be called only once thus only once they will load those images. also remember about `del self`

also try this:

```py
font = pg.font.SysFont('timesnewroman', 32)
text = font.render(message, True, 
        (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = (cell_number*cell_size / 2, cell_number*cell_size / 2)

class Main:
    
    def display_message(self, message):
            self.board.fill(game_over_color)
            self.board.blit(text, textRect)
```

take all those variables outside of the class and call only blitting in the class

Comment: did You read OP's code? do You understand the issue? the issue is that when pressing r key it should restart the game, look at the `reset()` method in Snake class. what does it do? it creates another instance of `Main` which means that it will run again through the `__init__` method and will again create an instance of `Snake` and `Food` which will call the `__init__` method of those classes (again) and load those images again. using `del self` would make sure that the previous `Main` instance is destroyed